# Can a simple Part expression produce a list of elements from nested lists?

Tags: list-manipulation

If `list1d` is a simple 1-d list, then `list1d[[{i, j, k}]]` evaluates to a *list* consisting of the `i`-th, `j`-th, and `k`-th element of `list1d`.

Is there an analogous construction for extracting a list of elements from nested lists?

---

More formally, if `list1d = Take[Alphabet[], 10]` (for example), then the following three expressions produce the same result, the *list* of elements `{"c", "g", "d"}`:

```
Part[list1d, Sequence @@ #] & /@ {{3}, {7}, {4}}           (* 1.1 *)

Part[list1d, {3, 7, 4}]                                    (* 1.2 *)

list1d[[{3, 7, 4}]]                                        (* 1.3 *)
```

But now suppose that `list2d = Partition[Alphabet[], UpTo[10]]`.  That is, `array2d` is a list of lists (with lengths 10, 10, and 6).

Then an expression analogous to 1.1 above

```
Part[list2d, Sequence @@ #] & /@ {{3, 3}, {1, 7}, {2, 4}}  (* 2.1 *)
```

...also evaluates to a *list* of elements (this time `{"w", "g", "n"}`).

Are there expressions analogous to 1.2 and 1.3 (and equivalent to 2.1) for the 2d case<sup>1</sup>?

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Here, by "analogous to 1.2 and 1.3", I mean that they are simple expressions with head `_Part`, and evaluating to a list of elements of `list2d`.</sup>

Comment: `Extract[array2d,{{3, 3}, {1, 7}, {2, 4}} ]`